# Need the URL of windows phone activesync

Tags: windows, mobile, exchange-server, windows-mobile, activesync

I have searched for hours. I am developing an activesync client in order to send sms from PC to a phone that will send it. Specifically a windows phone. Previously I have used Jeyo mobile comp. I have all documentation I need but I can't find the default http address of the activesync server on the Windows phone when it is connected through USB. I should mention that I have a disability and can't access Windows phone itself. The OS is 6 but the whole point of creating the software is so I can upgrade. Many thanks!
alternatively if I am barking up the wrong tree, i need to know what tree to bark. for example serial ports. i would only need code to connect and read/write. otherwise is there a way to detect the information with csharp, ipconfig definitely isn't detecting windows mobile and activesync definitely works.

Comment: Are you sure the upgrade of you Windows Phone is even possible?

Comment: Yes. Pretty sure. Saw models a few years ago at duty free. Not too concerned about data. Just need something that supports 3/4G, 2G is switched off in some parts of Austraila. Prefer sticking with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear. But Jeyo Mobile Comp is a remote control software for Windows Mobile (6.x, not Windows Phone 8 or 10).

Another free remote control software you my look at is Sparus EveryWan Remote personal edition (free). It can show the screen of Windows Mobile on your Windows PC and you can use the device remotely using the USB ActiveSync connection.

Another option is MyMobiler (also free).

The ActiveSync connection is made using the IP addresses 169.254.1.1 and 169.254.1.2 or 192.168.55.101/102, depends on Connection Setting:USB:Enhanced Network on device. You will find the IP when the device is connected to your PC, ActiveSync is connected and you start a Windows CMD prompt on the PC; then type "ipconfig" to get a list of IP addresses used by the PC. There will be your IP connected to the LAN/WAN and the one connected to Windows Mobile.

There is NO default http access to the Windows Mobile device.

If you are looking for a programming API, see RAPI at Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa513321.aspx) or OpenNetCF Desktop Communication (https://rapi.codeplex.com/) support.

Comment: Thanks but none of the addresses returned successful pings and i couldn't see it in ipconfig. Device is connected.

Comment: Please post a screenshot

Comment: sorry i'm not terribly comfortable posting screenshots of my system. i can say i saw two ethernet connections, one disconnected, one with lease date before i connected the phone . correction now I see only one after disabling a connection, router and activesync still works; both separate devices.

Comment: could it be you're assuming the phone has internet access, it does not, activesync definitely works with jeyo but i have no idea what address it uses, i'm beyond frustrated

Comment: ActiveSync or WMDC always uses a TCP/IP connection to talk with the device. In ActiveSync /or WMDC) you can define if the device will be connected to Work or Internet or Auto (see AS Connection Setings on PC). Yes, I am sure, Windows Mobile ActiveSync always uses IP for communication. There is one "USB to PC" setting on the device that defines if the device uses PPP or RNDIS. What about using EveryWAN Remote? You should now post ScreenShots of ipconfig output and your Connection Settings of AS on the PC with the device connected.

Comment: only the router ethernet and the main pc is showing in ipconfig /all i know how to read it. i heard something about serial ports and activesync. the only thing I can think of with your theory is i'm using the wrong parameter for ipconfig, let me know if this is the case

Comment: Something strange. The IP addresses used by WMDC/ActiveSync are (PC/Device); 169.254.2.2/1 or 192.168.55.100/101 (depends on USBToPC setting on device, PPP or RNDIS). Either your WMDC does not show device as connected or a firewall or something blocks this connection.

Comment: ping failed for all four ips, thanks for trying though

Comment: Then you do not have a standard active WMDC connection!